# имитировать нажатие(клик) по кнопке typescript

Tags: html, jquery, reactjs, typescript, sharepoint

Мне требуется при открытии страницы вызывать открытие окна фильтр-панели в Sharepoint.
Я использую Command Set Extension на react ts.
Я пробовал найти эту панель и задать ей display: block при загрузке страницы, однако этой секции кода с панелью нет в html, когда панель закрыта. (Изначально я полагал, она будет уходить в display: none, но увы...)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я думаю как-нибудь имитировать нажатие на кнопку открытия панели сразу после загрузки страницы. Может кто-нибудь подскажет, как можно реализовать это ?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [dispatchEvent](https://learn.javascript.ru/dispatch-events) и [React Ref](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), чтобы получить DOM элемент

```
const event = new Event("click");
FiltersPanelRef.current.dispatchEvent(event);
```